# solution for second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please support me on this problem. I have tried so hard but couldn't get the answer
$$
yy'' + yy' + 1 =0
$$
Thank you very much.

---

The original equation can be simplified to
$$y''+y'+\frac{1}{y}=0\tag{1}$$
using $u=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $y''=\frac{du}{dx}=u\frac{du}{dy}.$ Then Eqn. $(1)$:
$$u\frac{du}{dy}+u+\frac{1}{y}=0.\tag{2}$$
Eqn. $(2)$ can be reduced to $\frac{du}{dy}=-1-\frac{1}{uy}$, then
$$du=-dy- \frac{dy}{uy}.\tag{3}$$
Integrate both side of eqn. $(3)$: $u=-y- \int \frac{dy}{uy}.$ I am stuck right here. Anyone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: "I have tried so hard (...)" Please show us what you tried, as well as some background on the problem

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: y''+y'+1/y=0 (1)  using u=dy/dx; y''=du/dx=udu/dy. Then Eqn. (1): udu/dy+u+1/y=0 (2). Eq

Comment: The original equation can be simplified to y''+y'+1/y=0 (1) ; using u=dy/dx; y''=du/dx=udu/dy. Then Eqn. (1): udu/dy+u+1/y=0 (2). Eqn. (2) can be reduced to: du/dy=-1-1/(uy) then du=-dy- dy/(uy) (3). Integrate both side of eqn. (3) : u=-y- ∫dy/(uy). I am stuck right here. Anyone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Defining $u=y'(x)$, we can rewrite the ODE $yy''+yy'+1=0$ as
$$
yu\frac{du}{dy}+yu+1=0 \implies \frac{du}{dy}+1=-\frac{1}{yu}. \tag{1}
$$
Let $v:=u+y$; then
$$
\frac{dv}{dy}=\frac{du}{dy}+1=-\frac{1}{yu}=-\frac{1}{y(v-y)}
$$
$$
\implies\frac{dy}{dv}=y^2-vy. \tag{2}
$$
Equation $(2)$ is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation). It can be converted to a second order linear ODE with the substitution $y=-\frac{w'}{w}:$
$$
\frac{dy}{dv}=-\frac{w''}{w}+\frac{(w')^2}{w^2}=\frac{(w')^2}{w^2}+\frac{vw'}{w}
$$
$$
\implies w''+vw'=0 \implies w'=C_1e^{-v^2/2}\implies w=C_2+C_1\int_0^v e^{-t^2/2}\,dt, \tag{3}
$$
hence
$$
y(v)=-\frac{w'}{w}=\frac{C_1e^{-v^2/2}}{C_2+C_1\int_0^{v}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt} 
=\frac{e^{-v^2/2}}{a+\int_0^{v}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt}. \tag{4}
$$
Let's now determine $x(v)$, which, together with the expression for $y(v)$ given by Eq. $(4)$, yields the solution to the initial ODE in parametric form:
$$
\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{dy}{dx}=y''+y'=-\frac{1}{y}
\implies \frac{dx}{dv}=-y=\frac{w'}{w}
$$
$$
\implies x(v)=\ln(w)+b=\ln\left(a+\int_0^{v}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt\right)+b. \tag{5}
$$

Comment: Sorry, why in (1) the first addend is $yu \displaystyle \frac{du}{dy}$ instead of $y \displaystyle \frac{du}{dy}$?

Comment: Because $yy''=y\frac{dy'}{dx}=y\frac{dy'}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=y\frac{du}{dy}u$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If I have the boundary conditions, please let me know how can we solve for constants a and b. For example if y(x=0)=y0 and y'(x=0)= A. Thank you very much

Comment: Let $v_0:=v(x=0)$; then, according to the definition of $v$ (given after Eq. $(1)$), $v_0=u(x=0)+y(x=0)=y'(x=0)+y(x=0)=A+y_0$. Now, use Eq. $(4)$ with $y(v_0)=y_0$ to determine $a$, and Eq. $(5)$ with $x(v_0)=0$ to determine $b$.

Answer (score 1):

$$yy''+yy'+1=0$$
This is a second order ODE of the autonomous kind. As already noted in comment the usual way to reduce the order is the change of function :
$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=u(y) \quad\implies\quad \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=u\frac{du}{dy}$$
$$y\,u\frac{du}{dy}+y\,u+1=0$$
Let $v(y)=u(y)+y\quad\implies\quad \frac{du}{dy}=\frac{dv}{dy}-1$
$$y\,(v-y)(\frac{dv}{dy}-1)+y\,(v-y)+1=0$$
$$y\,(v-y)\frac{dv}{dy}+1=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dv}=(y-v)y$$
This is a first order ODE of the Riccati kind. The usual way to solve it is the change of function :

$y=-\frac{1}{w(v)}\frac{dw}{dv}\quad\implies\quad \frac{dy}{dv}=-\frac{1}{w}\frac{d^2w}{dv^2}+\frac{1}{w^2}\left(\frac{dw}{dv}\right)^2$
$$-\frac{1}{w}\frac{d^2w}{dv^2}+\frac{1}{w^2}\left(\frac{dw}{dv}\right)^2=\left(-\frac{1}{w(v)}\frac{dw}{dv}-v\right)\left(-\frac{1}{w(v)}\frac{dw}{dv} \right)$$

$$\frac{d^2w}{dv^2}=-v\frac{dw}{dv}$$
$$\frac{dw}{dv}=c_1\exp\left(-\frac12 v^2 \right)$$
$$w(v)=c_1\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{erf}\left(\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+c_2$$
Now one has to come back to $\quad y(v)=-\frac{1}{w(v)}\frac{dw}{dv}\quad$ then to the inverse function i.e.: $v(y)$ then to  $\quad u(y)=v(y)-y\quad$ then to $\quad x(y)=\int \frac{dy}{u(y)}\quad$ then to the inverse function $y(x)$ which is the final solution. This is the theory but in fact the closed forms doesn't exist in terms of a finit number of standard functions.

As a consequence in practice numerical calculus is necessary. So the simplest way is to solve directly the original ODE thanks to numerical method of calculus.

Note that simplifications might appear in particular cases of boundary conditions eventualy making possible the analytical solving.

Comment: Thank you very much!